# Create matrix from vector with all vector elements shifted down 2 steps

Tags: r

Say I have

```
v = rbind(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
# > v
# [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    1
# [3,]    0
# [4,]    0
# [5,]    0
# [6,]    0
```

How would I get to this?

```
# > m
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,]    1     0     0
# [2,]    1     0     0
# [3,]    0     1     0 
# [4,]    0     1     0
# [5,]    0     0     1
# [6,]    0     0     1
```

Comment: `expand.grid` was a candidate, I thought, and yes this is a trivial question. After many hours of work this is the thing I'd ask the collegue next to me, and conclude with a d'oh because I am sure it is obvious. But I am alone in the office so naturally I assume SO could provide a quick reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add two zeros and recycle the vector:

```
v1 <- c(v,0,0)
m <- matrix(v1,ncol=3,nrow=6)
```

(ignore the warning)

```
> m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    0
#[4,]    0    1    0
#[5,]    0    0    1
#[6,]    0    0    1
```